# How to associate an arraylist with my object?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have class Tile.  I have 37 instances of Tile objects and I would like each Tile object to hold 3 different arraylists, or any collection really, I am not sure which is best suited for my needs.

Right now my class is set up like this:

```
public class Tile {  
    public Tile n0;
    public Tile n1;
    public Tile n2;
    public Tile n3;
    public Tile n4;
    public Tile n5;

    public Tile (){

    }
    public Tile (Terrain ter){

    }

    public void initNeighbours(){
        //middle column
        Tile t0 = new Tile();
        Tile t1 = new Tile();
        Tile t2 = new Tile();
        Tile t3 = new Tile();
        Tile t4 = new Tile();
        Tile t5 = new Tile();
        Tile t6 = new Tile(); 

        //middle column
        //t0
        t0.n0 = null;
        t0.n1 = null;
        t0.n2 = t7;
        t0.n3 = t1;
        t0.n4 = t22;
        t0.n5 = null;
    etc
    }
}
```

I want to have a collection of Creature Objects, a collection of Building objects and a collection of gold pieces.  I would like to be able to print out what is on each tile, add and remove things, remove things from one tile and add the same thing into a collection on another tile.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `List<Creature>`, `List<Building>` and `int` for gold?

Comment: This question's a bit of a bait 'n' switch.  You start with wanting to associate a list in the title, but are looking for a full multi-component design in your question body.

Comment: any chance you can make another class, that holds a tile object + the other two things (gold/buildings) if I understand , and use only one slot in the say... array ?

Comment: I'm really not sure if this is something that's even possible, I'm sorry if it looks like bait and switch, I am not competent enough to know what is and is not possible, I just can't find out until I'm told otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is going to be a very high-level answer, no code.

### The `Tile`

You have a hexagonal grid. Make a `Tile` class with `Tile[6]` neighbours (plain array). Make an external function (possibly as part of your Main class) which will initialize the grid, perhaps reading its configuration from a file, or whatever other source you have (even hard-coded) -- point is to keep the `Tile` class clean.

What can each tile have? This is the critical question. I would tend to assume that you are making a sort of a game where you can put objects on this hexagonal grid, and this looks like each grid can have *either* a creature *or* a piece of gold *or* a building. I'll go on with this assumption (you haven't really defined these things).

### The `TileObject`

Now in order to simplify the guarantee that a tile can have just one object, you introduce an abstract type, a `TileObject`. Depending on your later needs you can make this either an abstract class or an interface. Your `Creature`, `Gold` and `Building` all inherit from ths class/interface.

Now you can consider how to manage these types and what sort of relationships between them you actually need. For starters, it is clear that each `Tile` knows its `TileObject`, if any.

If you also need to know for any given `TileObject`, to what `Tile` it belongs, obviously you need a `Tile` backreference. I'd put it in `TileObject` and make `TileObject` an abstract class.

The `Collections`

If you need to be able to enumerate all tiles, You'd need a Tile collection. Keep it separate from the `Tile` class, maybe in your `Main` class. Make sure it's an unordered collection (just because an ordering makes no sense), I'd go with a `HashSet`. If you need to be able to enumerate all `TileObjects`, make an unordered collection of them. If you need to be able to enumerate all individual types of objects, skip the all-inclusive collection and go for three seperate ones. If you need to represent objects that haven't been placed yet, that have been consumed but need to be tracked, etc. I'd make a collection for each bunch, it'll make enumerating them separately easier.

### The actions

Now's the tricky part. You need to define very clear semantics of what can be done on the grid. For every action that can be taken, you need to define a very clear method, most likely in the `Tile` class.

Consider `Tile.place (TileObject tileObject)`: Obviously, if the tile is empty, anything can be placed on it. Make sure to set the forward-reference (`this.tileObject = tileObject`) as well as the back-reference (`tileObject.tile = this`). Have you checked that tileObject doesn't already have a `tile` set? If the tile is not empty, what kind of placement is compatible, if any?

Consider `Tile.moveFrom (Tile tile)`: it needs to make sure that the target tile (`this`) is either empty or has an object compatible for being replaced by the object contained in the source tile (`tile`). `tile.tileObject` must be non-null. You must updated two forward-references and one back-reference.

Consider, for example, the concept of consumption of gold by a creature (or a player). The `Tile.moveFrom (Tile tile)` action needs to recognize this. How many special cases are there? If just one, handle it right there. If many, implement each specific *A placed over B* case in the appropriate `TileObject`: `Tile.move` additionally calls `tile.tileObject.placedOver(this.tileObject)`. If you have many `TileObject` subtypes, and many valid, but specific combinations of being placed over, you will want [multimethods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimethods), but I'm digressing.

Consider the death of a creature `Creature.destroy ()`: it needs to delete itself from its tile. You need to remove it from the collection of creatures/tile objects. Maybe you need to know which creatures died, in that case move it to a dedicated `deadCreatures/TileObjects` collection and so on.

For each possible action, you will have to think very hard about all the consequences, implement them in methods which clearly state the intent, and then you can play with the whole thing. Maybe you have rules like "If this happens on a Tile, then this happens on its neighbours (perhaps with a probability)" -- then it gets a bit more complicated.

And for God's sake, skip the getters and setters -- you're not writing an API.

Comment: I meant to say thank you, but I forgot, so thank you!  The project I am undertaking is the largest I have had to do to date and I have been getting confused at the smallest things.  Thank you for helping me  sort things out in my mind, I really appreciate everything you've given me to think about!

Answer (score 1):

So do you need a collection of Tile objects in each Tile object, or collection of Creature, Building, and Gold? I would consider rewriting so all objects which can be contained in a tile, extend an abstract TileData class or something.. So you could just have 1 list of

`ArrayList<TileData> stuffOnThisTile;`

But here is something which might help? Again, not sure what you're looking for.

```
public class Tile {
//public Tile n0;
//public Tile n1;
//public Tile n2;
//public Tile n3;
//public Tile n4;
//public Tile n5;
private ArrayList<Tile> tiles;
private ArrayList<Creature> creatures;
private ArrayList<Building> buildings;
private ArrayList<Gold> golds;

public Tile (){
    initLists();
}
public Tile (Terrain ter){

}

private void initLists(){
    tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    creatures = new ArrayList<Creature>();
    buildings = new ArrayList<Building>();
    golds = new ArrayList<Gold>();

}

public boolean addGold(Gold g){
    golds.add(g);
    return true;

}

public Gold getGoldByIndex(int index){
    return golds.get(index);
}

public ArrayList<Gold> getAllGold(){
    return golds;
}

public String toString(){
    String returnString = "";
    for (Building b : buildings){
        returnString += b.toString();
    }
    for (Creature c : creatures){
        returnString += c.toString();
    }
    for (Gold g : golds){
        returnString += g.toString();
    }
    return returnString;

}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been very clear in my question, but I'm not sure what I need exactly.  I have made a grid of a bunch of hex tiles, each hex tile has 6 neighbours, and I need to keep track of the neighbours to track if I am making valid moves over the board of hex tiles.  So I need each tile to hold it's relations to other tiles, and then I also need it to hold lists of other stuff...  What you've provided is very helpful, I'm just not sure how to have the tile still hold it's relations to it's neighbours

Comment: I would probably do something to keep track of each of the 6 neighbours by defining some variables in a static constants class, ex: byte N = 0, NE = 1, SE = 2, S = 3, SW = 4, NW = 5 (these will be used as indexes for accessing the array). Then in your tile class, make an array that holds 6 items, so `Tile[] neighbours = new Tile[6];` Then when you could write methods to get/set a specific neighbour, like `public Tile getTileByIndex(byte index)`... which would then return neighbours[index];